# AngularJs Filter with groupby in Controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

I have a JSON filter in view

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, value) in TData.Files
            | map: toLocaleDate
            | groupBy: 'da'">
<div><strong>{ Date:</strong> "{{ key }}" , Count: {{value.length}} } ,</div>
```

using a filter in controller

```
$scope.toLocaleDate = function (e) {
                var date = e.da.split(" ");
                e.da = date[0];
                return e;
            };
```

Now i Want to Have the Filtered Data into Another JSON Object. So i need to do th e filter in controller rather than in View .. How to implement that?

The expected result is like

```
[{'Date':"2012-01-12", Count:5},{'Date':"2012-01-13", Count:8}, ....]
```

Comment: use $filter so that you can filter data in controller

Comment: I solved it by var newData = $filter('groupBy')(OriginalData, 'FieldName');

Answer (score 0):

As there is no default filter groupBy in angularjs So You have to make a filter for that
and you can use any filter in the controller just explained as

Inject the `$filter` dependency and in controller just use the simple syntax

```
$filter('filtername')('arraydata', 'other arguments');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/R8YZh/35/

Answer (score 0):

If you need that in js code. You can use an injected method of angular-filter lib. The Filter "group by" is a part of this library. Use it like this.

```
function controller($scope, $http, groupByFilter) {     

   var groupedData = groupByFilter(originalArray, 'groupPropName');

}
```

https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter/wiki/Common-Questions#inject-filters